# Extracting XML field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, crystal-reports-2008

I have `fldxml` column in a `MIWOD` table that contains multiple type of data. How can I display `[fldxml]` column value as shown below?

```
 Routing      Drawing
      1       C:\Users\XXX\Documents\LETTUCE_WHEEL.pdf
```

Here is how `[fldxml]` looks like

```
<fields> 
    <field1>1</field1>
    <field2>C:\Users\XXX\Documents\LETTUCE_WHEEL.pdf</field2>
</fields>
```

I want get something like this

```
Routing      Drawing:
   1         C:\Users\XXX\Documents\LETTUCE_WHEEL.pdf
```

I tried using the following

```
SELECT 
    MIWOD.fldXml('(field1/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Routing,
    MIWOD.fldXml('(field1/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Routing
FROM  
    [MISAMPCO].[dbo].[MIWOD]
```

But I get the following error

> Cannot find either column "MIWOD" or the user-defined function or aggregate "MIWOD.fldXml", or the name is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @stuff xml

SET @stuff = '<fields><field1>1</field1><field2>C:\Users\Kinfe\Documents\LETTUCE_WHEEL.pdf</field2></fields>'

SELECT 
    Child.value('field1[1]', 'int') [**Routing:**], 
    Child.value('field2[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [**Drawing:**]
FROM 
    @stuff.nodes('fields[1]') as N(Child)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! The works Great! How can i apply  the same in Crystal Report, Any idea?. I want to display these two fields in my report

Comment: I also want instead of `SET @stuff = '<fields><field1>1</field1><field2>C:\Users\Kinfe\Documents\LETTUCE_WHEEL.pdf</field2></fields>'` i Want to use something like  `SET @stuff = 'fldXml'` the field itself. Thanks!!

Comment: I just used an xml variable so the code would be testable by anyone. If the xml is in a column, it can be queried like so (hopefully this helps you with Crystal Report, a thing I know nothing about unfortunately): 
`create table Junk(id int, CoolData xml);
insert into Junk values (1, '<fields><field1>1</field1><field2>C:\Users\Kinfe\Documents\LETTUCE_WHEEL.pdf</field2></fields>');

SELECT 
    CoolData.value('(fields/field1)[1]', 'int') [**Routing:**], 
    CoolData.value('(fields/field2)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [**Drawing:**]
FROM Junk WHERE id = 1`